# jQuery Find class and store it as a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple of `<div>` which have classes in them of `timeline-year-` and then the year attached.

I'm trying to find the class with the year and extract the year into a variable to append the text inside the `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ubL7h10u/

```
<div class="jsn-bootstrap3 timeline-events timeline-year-2012">
    Year
</div>
<div class="jsn-bootstrap3 timeline-events timeline-year-2011">
    Year
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the ways to do it using `text` method and a little regular expession:

```
$('[class*="timeline-year"]').text(function () {
    return $(this).text() + ' ' + this.className.match(/timeline-year-(\d+)?/)[1];
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ubL7h10u/8/

But you would make your code cleaner if you went with this:

```
<div class="jsn-bootstrap3 timeline-events" data-year="2012">Year</div>
<div class="jsn-bootstrap3 timeline-events" data-year="2011">Year</div>
```

and then:

```
$('.timeline-events').text(function () {
    return $(this).text() + ' ' + $(this).data('year');
});
```

or event with just CSS in this case:

```
.timeline-events:after {
    content: ' ' attr(data-year);
}
```

#### CSS demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ubL7h10u/10/

Comment: (close the class attributes before data)

Comment: This would be a brilliant method to use, unfortunately `data-year` cannot be set, it can only be used as a class at the moment. But great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the year text off of the class attribute.

```
$('[class*="timeline-year"]').each(function(){
    var classString = $(this).attr('class');
    var year = classString.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    console.log(year);
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ubL7h10u/9/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[class*="timeline-year"]').each(function(){
            var year = $(this);
            var list = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
            for(var i =0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
                if(list[i].indexOf("timeline-year") !== -1)
                {
                    $(this).html(list[i].split("-")[2])
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it : **get the content of class attribute, then get the last 4 characters of that string** : http://jsfiddle.net/ubL7h10u/5/

```
$('[class*="timeline-year"]').each(function(){
        var classname = $(this).attr('class');
        var year = classname.substr(classname.length - 4);
        console.log(year);
    });
```